# Соответствие схемы SQLAlchemy реальным таблицам БД

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Есть существующая БД на PostgreSQL. С помощью SQLAlchemy я реализовал схему этой БД.

Есть ли способ средствами SQLAlchemy (или отдельный пакет Python) проверить, не допустил ли я ошибку при описании схемы?

Интерисует все: имена таблиц, столбцов (их тип и длина), первичные и внешние ключи.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Проще будет при построении схемы воспользоваться метаданными из БД, использовав [DB object reflection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html):

```
messages = Table('messages', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
[c.name for c in messages.columns]
#['message_id', 'message_name', 'date']
```

[Ограничения](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#limitations-of-reflection):

> **Limitations of Reflection**
>
> It’s important to note that the reflection process recreates Table
>   metadata using only information which is represented in the relational
>   database. This process by definition cannot restore aspects of a
>   schema that aren’t actually stored in the database. State which is not
>   available from reflection includes but is not limited to:
>
> Client side defaults, either Python functions or SQL expressions
>   defined using the default keyword of Column (note this is separate
>   from server_default, which specifically is what’s available via
>   reflection). Column information, e.g. data that might have been placed
>   into the Column.info dictionary The value of the .quote setting for
>   Column or Table The association of a particular Sequence with a given
>   Column The relational database also in many cases reports on table
>   metadata in a different format than what was specified in SQLAlchemy.
>   The Table objects returned from reflection cannot be always relied
>   upon to produce the identical DDL as the original Python-defined Table
>   objects. Areas where this occurs includes server defaults,
>   column-associated sequences and various idosyncrasies regarding
>   constraints and datatypes. Server side defaults may be returned with
>   cast directives (typically PostgreSQL will include a :: cast) or
>   different quoting patterns than originally specified.
>
> Another category of limitation includes schema structures for which
>   reflection is only partially or not yet defined. Recent improvements
>   to reflection allow things like views, indexes and foreign key options
>   to be reflected. As of this writing, structures like CHECK
>   constraints, table comments, and triggers are not reflected.

Comment: Спасибо. Как вариант вполне пойдет

Comment: @Alex, [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/).

Использовать очень просто - `sqlacodegen postgresql:///some_local_db > file.txt`

Выгружает в файл полную модель БД со всеми связями